# conversion of String to int and int to String c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do some calculation of car prices.
I tried to get the car price and convert that to int and then multiply the int value to a percentage and then display the result in another textbox.

This what i've done and it throws exception:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int carPrice = Convert.ToInt32(txtCarPrice.Text);
    carPrice = int.Parse(txtCarPrice.Text);
    int downPayment = Convert.ToInt32(txtDownPayment.Text);
    downPayment = int.Parse(txtDownPayment.Text);
    downPayment = Convert.ToInt32(carPrice * .2);
    txtDownPayment.Text = downPayment.ToString("0.#####");
}
```

It Throws a format Exception!

Comment: Most of your code is unnecessary.  `Convert.ToInt32` and `int.Parse` in this case behave the same.  Additionally, the value of `downPayment` is always determined by `carPrice` so you shouldn't bother reading from `txtDownPayment.Text`.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(carPrice * .2);` is not an int would be `decimal` or `double`

Comment: which line is throwing the format exception?

Answer (score 0):

You have couple problems in your code:

1. It situation when string empty `Convert.ToInt32` and `int.Parse`will throw Format Exception, so you need to check string before parsing.
2. Result of multiplying `int` on `doulbe` will be `double` so you need to store it in `double` variable. Converting result to `int' will cause exception or loss of the fractional part.
3. You don't need to parse value twice using `Convert.ToInt32(txtCarPrice.Text)` and `int.Parse(txtCarPrice.Text)`.
4. Value of `txtDownPayment` not used, so you don't need to read and parse it.

I guess you need something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCarPrice.Text))
      return;
  int carPrice = Convert.ToInt32(txtCarPrice.Text);
  double downPayment = carPrice * .2;
  txtDownPayment.Text = downPayment.ToString("0.#####");
}
```